# How to restrict affecting range with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, selector

```
<table>
...
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(selecctor).click(...)
</script>
```

The above is to be dynamic loaded by ajax.

What I want to do is restrict the `selector` so that it only affects the DOM within the `table` above it.I( can't assign an `id`to the `table`)

**EDIT**

To Gumbo's solution:

```
<div id="container">
</div>
<table>
..
</table>
```

I think for the above html,it will fail,because `$('table:last')` is not the newly loaded `table`,but the `table` after `container`

Answer (score 1):

You can [pass a context element](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) with the second parameter:

```
$("selector", $("table")).click(...)
```

Then the selector is evaluated based on that context.

---

**Edit**    Try `table:last` to select the last added node:

```
$("selector", $("table:last")).click(...)
```

This should work as only the nodes up to the `SCRIPT` element are already added to the DOM. But this does only work if you call `$` directly and not via `$.ready` or `$(document).ready`.

Comment: `$("table")` is not enough to restrict the affecting range.

Comment: @user198729: Then how can you identify that particular table out of context?

Comment: To your edited answwer:the container is not necessarily located at the end of `body`.

Comment: @user198729: But you’re still referring to the nearest preceding table, right?

Answer (score 1):

You should show the whole html being loaded via ajax, as well as the html that will receive the loaded content.

But, say you are loading this table inside a div#mycontent and assuming there will only be one table:

```
$('#mycontent table:first').click();
```

Or better, assuming you should call your javascript in the ajax callback and separate the js and the html

```
$('#mycontent').load('file.php',function(data){
var selector = $('table',data).eq(0);
});
```

Comment: This way will definately work.However,I want to make it possible that all I need to do is `$('container').load('file.php')`.The listeners are added in `file.php` itself.

Comment: well, i'm sorry to tell you this: there is no *reliable way* to do what you ask. Why do you keep such bad constraints (not separating the code and the behaviour, not giving an id or class to your table) ?
Why use jquery if you don't use it the way it should be used?

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the table.

```
<table class="myUniqueClass">...</table>

$(".myUniqueClass").click(...);
```

Comment: The `table` may be loaded multiple times,each time populated with different data.

Comment: And... if you explain a little more about what you are doing you may get the help you need.

Comment: if you are trying to reference some part of a dynamically loaded page using the jQuery.load method you can do something like
$("#Container").load("myfile.php .myUniqueClass");

Comment: I don't want to leave the listener-adding jobs to the **loading** page,but the **loaded** page instead